# Auxiliary class

Tags: ldap, active-directory

I try to modify an AD schema, adding a **custom auxiliary class** in user (Cn=MyName,CN=Users,DC=xxx,DC=yyy)

With **adsiedit** when the new object window pops-up to add the class, I can only select "classStore, ms-net..., nTRSSSubscriptions"

I added "user" in "Possible superior", but no change. I cannot see my custom class!